# Multiple IIFs and CHARINDEXs searches to extract data from same column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, iif, charindex

This is MS SQL Server 2017.

This currently works. I just can't believe that this is the best way to perform these actions.

The `Meeting` table is populated from multiple services. It has a `MeetingComment` column that we used to encode some additional information from some of those sources but is unused by other sources. I want to extract some of the coded information, when used, into separate columns: `Source` and `MeetingType`.

| MeetingComment | Source | MeetingType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `{{{[ASTRA][CLASS][TMR:OFF]}}} ...` | ASTRA | CLASS |
| `{{{[ASTRA][CLASS][MERGED][TMR:OFF]}}} ...` | ASTRA | CLASS |
| `{{{[ASTRA][EVENT:Study Session][TMR:OFF]}}} ...` | ASTRA | EVENT:Study Session |
| `{{{[ASTRA][EVENT:Meeting][TMR:OFF]}}} ...` | ASTRA | EVENT:Meeting |
| `{{{[ASTRA][EVENT:Maintenance][TMR:ON]}}} ...` | ASTRA | EVENT:Maintenance |
|  | UNK | UNK |

Here is the SQL that I currently have that is working:

```
    SELECT 
      Meeting.MeetingID, 
      Meeting.MeetingComment, 
      Meeting.Subject, 
      Rooms.RoomName, 
      IIF(
        CHARINDEX(
          '{{{[', Meeting.MeetingComment
        ) = 1, 
        SUBSTRING(
          Meeting.MeetingComment, 
          5, 
          CHARINDEX(
            ']', Meeting.MeetingComment
          )-5
        ), 
        'UNK'
      ) AS Source, 
      IIF(
        CHARINDEX(
          '{{{[', Meeting.MeetingComment
        ) = 1, 
        SUBSTRING(
          Meeting.MeetingComment, 
          CHARINDEX(
            '[', 
            Meeting.MeetingComment, 
            (
              CHARINDEX(
                '[', Meeting.MeetingComment, 
                1
              )
            ) + 2
          ) + 1, 
          CHARINDEX(
            ']', 
            Meeting.MeetingComment, 
            (
              CHARINDEX(
                ']', Meeting.MeetingComment, 
                1
              )
            )+ 2
          )- CHARINDEX(
            '[', 
            Meeting.MeetingComment, 
            (
              CHARINDEX(
                '[', Meeting.MeetingComment, 
                1
              )
            ) + 2
          ) -1
        ), 
        'UNK'
      ) AS MeetingType, 
      Meeting.Recurrence, 
      Meeting.Location
```

But, as a programmer, it bugs me to have to use the same conditional test (the IIF statements) for both fields and to have to do the same CHARINDEX lookups multiple times. So before I move on, I just wanted to check to see if there is a better way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This *looks* lke SQL Server? Please tag your Databasr and state its version.

Comment: Ok -added tag and version. I will test the proposed solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your example you are simply after the content of the first and second set of brackets.

Assuming the current version of SQL Server a more elegant solution would be a little parsing with *json* conbined with *conditional aggregation*:

```
select MeetingComment, Max([Source]) [Source], Max(MeetingType) MeetingType
from t
cross apply (
  select  
    case when [key]='1' then j.[value] end [Source],
    case when [key]='3' then j.[value] end MeetingType
  from OpenJson(Concat('["', replace(Translate(MeetingComment,'[]',',,'), ',', '","'), '"]')) j
)s
group by MeetingComment;
```

Comment: I may not have implemented it correctly, but I get the following error: `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS`